# What is the proper way to do a page reload in react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

What is the proper way to do a page reload using react-router-redux?

We normally push a new state in actions this way,

```
export function doTask() {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch(DoTask.request());
        fetch(`${API}/doTask`, get())
            .then(status)
            .then(_ => dispatch(doTask.success()))
            .then(_ => dispatch(push('/dashboard')))
            .catch(error => dispatch(DoTask.failure(error))) }}
```

and I was wondering if it's a good practice to trigger a page reload this way,

```
.then(_ => window.location.reload())
```

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: The easiest way to reload the entire page is to just window.location.reload() also the Router has a refresh method. It might be what you need. https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v0.13.3/modules/createRouter.js#L435-L437

Comment: I'm using react-router-redux, does it have an equivalent? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `window.location.reload()`